# Why explicit wait is waiting for entire wait time even though element is visible/clickable before the wait time is over

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have given a wait time for 60 sec, and i am using wait until element to be clickable/visible but script is waiting for whole 30 secs even though the element is visible on UI and also clickable?

I tried using latest selenium version, tried using different waits also using different locators. but it did not work

Comment: Does it throw 'TimeOutException' exception or just wait? and you should add your code.

Comment: In some cases it throws the exception but in most cases it will wait for entire time and the perform operation. Below is the the method to click on one element. (I have used similar similar waits.), wait time is 60 seconds         public viod clickReset(){
      genericPage.scrollUp();
     wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(resetLink));
     resetLink.click();
    }

Answer (score 1):

The reasons could be in:

1. The element belongs to [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) so you need to switch to the iframe prior to attempting locating anything inside it
2. The element belongs to [Shadow DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM)  so you need to locate [ShadowRoot](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ShadowRoot) object, cast it to the WebElement and find the sub-element you want to click
3. Your locator is not correct, try getting the page source and saving it to a file. Once done use your favourite [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) to locate the elemen
4. The syntax of your Explicit Wait is not correct. Check out [Explicit Waits](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits) and [How to use Selenium to test web applications using AJAX technology](https://experitest.com/selenium-testing/ajax_technology_selenium/) for code examples

Going forward consider adding page source and your code to your question as the chance you will get the comprehensive answer will be much higher, otherwise we have to go for "blind shots"

Comment: it script performs the operation after waiting for entire wait time, but i am not able to understand that if element is visible or clickable then why my script is waiting for entire wait time. Below is a method i am using.                                                    public void getAminitiesFilter(){
        WebElement amenityFilter=  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//label[@for='amenity']")));
     genericPage.scrollToElement(amenityFilter);
    }